# Which HTML5 Media JS Framework is Best?

Tags: jquery, html, video, canvas, media

I want to customize a video player to have additional buttons and controls using jquery. I've found two that seem like viable candidates, and I'm interested in hearing which is better (or if there's yet another one that's best). Please keep in mind that my goal is to modify it (not just drop and play).

Here are the two candidates I've found so far:

1. http://videojs.com/
2. http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=loop this page demonstrating adding button/features looks promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading details about both the Framework, I vote for http://mediaelementjs.com/. It is has more configuration option than VideoJS.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Popcorn.js.  It has quite a few features and is open-source.

http://popcornjs.org/